# How to read all Files from One folder and Merge to Single file in a sorting order

Tags: java, python-3.x

I am trying to read all files in a folder and merge them into different file. When the file is merged I want to make sure the merged file content is in sorting order.

Content of each file will be in this format.

TimeStamp, Number1, Tesxt1
2020-01-22 11:22:33.323,12313,test1

Currently i have created java program to sort and merge two files. but I want to make sure i can read from all files in dictory and merge to one (sorting by timestamp).

Can someone kindly help me with the code please. I am open for any technology. Java or Python and etc.,

Comment: Hi , what have you tried ?

Comment: Here is my program i have. this is basically reading files from directory and copying to new fiile.

Comment: File dir = new File("Path 2 directory");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file path");
        String[] fileNames = dir.list();
        for (String fileName : fileNames) {
            System.out.println("Reading from " + fileName);
            File f = new File(dir, fileName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            pw.println("Contents of file " + fileName);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                pw.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            } pw.flush();}

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, this can be done as a one-liner using standard utilities:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | sort > file4
```

Seeing that your timestamp is the first field and in YMD HMS format, a simple alphabetic sort will render the file in chronological order. Here, three files are concatenated, then passed through sort (default is alphanumeric, ascending order), and the result redirected to a new file.

Windows batch utilities should have the same capabilities.

Comment: Unfortunately I donot have Linux Cornel. I had to go with Java program. I cld use python. but there are limitation in using from libraries. so  i had to rely on java for now